# Magento 2 order mass action xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, magento-2.0

So i was making a mass action for orders and i was searching for what this:

```
<item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete_order</item>
```

line of xml does and what its used for in the

`/view/adminhtml/ui_components/sales_order_grid.xml`

The whole file looks like this:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <action name="new_action">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete_order</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Orders</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="{vendor}_{module}/order/DeleteOrder"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

So can someone **explain** to what it does?